# AddEventListener for Click is not working with AS2.0 and Flash Player 10

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, flash-cs5

I have the following code  from [Adobe](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00002328.html):

```
myListener = new Object();
myListener.click = function(evt){
    trace(evt.type + " triggered");
}
myButton.addEventListener("click", myListener);
```

But this does not work though the btn on stage have the same Instance name as in code.

Comment: The code you read is meant to be used with the Button component. Are you sure you are using a component (taken from the components window)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code provided only works with the actual button *component*.  A button *symbol* does not dispatch a `click` event and does not have an `addEventListener` method. You would have to change your code to:

```
myButton.onRelease = function() {
    trace("click triggered");
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is working with Button component only. Any idea how to add event listener to a button symbol. Or Any way I can instantiate button component in code?